# Part of my coding in javascript not working

Tags: javascript, validation

For some reason, the validation for duration is having problem such as when I try to type 30000000 for the duration and submit,it just never do its validation but the rest of the validation works for some reason.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>

function validateForm() {
    var x = document.forms["myForm"]["token","id","percentage","duration"].value;
    if (x == "") {
        alert("There are empty fields");
        return false;
    }
    var y =document.forms.myForm.percentage.value;
    if(y>=0 && y<=100)
    {
    return true;
    }
    else
    {
    alert("Percentage output must be between 0 and 100");
    return false;
    }

    var k =document.forms.myForm.duration.value;
    if(k>=0 && k<=30000)
    {
    return true;
   }
   else{
   alert("Error");
   return false;
   }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form name="myForm" onSubmit="return validateForm();">
Enter access token: <input type="text" name="token">
Enter device id: <input type="text" name="id">
Enter output percentage: <input type="text" name="percentage">
Enter duration(in milliseconds) of output: <input type="text" name="duration">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Java has nothing to do with JavaScript.

Comment: When you debug this, where specifically does it fail?  "It doesn't work" isn't a problem description.

Comment: It just resets without doing the validation

Comment: Also, the next time you post, you may want to be more specific with your title as it's very vague.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cause:

```
function validateForm() {
    var x = document.forms["myForm"]["token","id","percentage","duration"].value;
    if (x == "") {
        alert("There are empty fields");
        return false;
    }
    var y =document.forms.myForm.percentage.value;
    if(y>=0 && y<=100)
    {
    return true;   //<---- You leave your code here!!
    }
    else
    {
    alert("Percentage output must be between 0 and 100");
    return false;
    }

    var k =document.forms.myForm.duration.value;
    if(k>=0 && k<=30000)
    {
    return true;
   }
   else{
   alert("Error");
   return false;
   }
}
```

Look at the arrow in the code I entered.

In the percentage check, you always return! The duration check is never reached. You should remove all your if/else cases which ends in return `true`, only check on error and return `false` in that case. Otherwise return `true` as the last line of your method.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to alert on more than one error, you can do something like the following, though you'd have to format the alert message text so that each error is on its own line:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>

    function validateForm() {
        var errors = [];
        var x = document.forms["myForm"]["token","id","percentage","duration"].value;
        if (x == "") {
            alert("There are empty fields");
            return false;
        }
        var percentage = document.forms.myForm.percentage.value;
        if(!(percentage >= 0 && percentage <= 100)) {
            errors.push("Percentage output must be between 0 and 100");
        }

        var duration = document.forms.myForm.duration.value;
        if(!(duration >= 0 && duration <= 30000)) {
            errors.push("Duration output must be between 0 and 30,000");
        }

        if (errors.length > 0) {
            alert(errors);
        }
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form name="myForm" onSubmit="return validateForm();">
<p>Enter access token: <input type="text" name="token"/></p>
<p>Enter device id: <input type="text" name="id"/></p>
<p>Enter output percentage: <input type="text" name="percentage"/></p>
<p>Enter duration(in milliseconds) of output: <input type="text" name="duration"/></p>
<p><input type="submit" value="Submit"/></p>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```